# Realm databases and compatibility between different schemas

Tags: android, realm

I am creating Android app and need a way to store data and sync with server so i have posibility to have access to the same data from different devices and places. I am consider using Realm Database. I think that it will match all my requirements. But i have one question. Let assume that we released version 1.0 of our application, few users have access to one realm (lets name it REALM-ONE), they are making changes there(insert, update, delete). In meanwhile we developed a next version of our app with a little changed schema, i mean we add one property to the object and make a breaking changes in another(e.g. merge two properties into one and change data type). Part of the REALM-ONE users updated app to the newest version(other users cannot because of too old version of android), and i want everyone to have opportunity to still using the REALM-ONE as before without need to update app. Quick diagram:[image]
According to [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#syncing-migrations) i know what will happen with new property, it will update on server and be visible in v2.0 but surely should not be visible for previous version of the app. And what with breaking changes ? Can i support this change in v1.0 ? Can it still collaborate together ? Can I managed it with realm notifications or realm functions ?

Comment: Realm Sync disallows destructive migration, so properties that are removed but were part of the schema are just ignored in new version. So old users will use the old field, new version will use the new field. You most likely cannot change data type without creating a new field.

Comment: Thank You for answer, so You tell me that when i delete something form schema and add something new, the old version will still work and use the old ones while the new version will just ignore old properties and uses those added to new schema right ?

Comment: AFAIK that's how it is